# 24 VDC signal to Raspberry Pi GPIO input via optocoupler not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, opto-isolator, gpio

I am new to the whole universe of electric circuits and could not get my head fully around my problem. Please bear with me.

I have a 24 VDC signal that is switched on and off by a relay. My Raspberry Pi needs to read the signal. As I don't want to harm the RPi, I read about using a optocoupler to galvanically separate both circuits. I am using a [Kingbright KB817-M optocoupler](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000140363DS01/datenblatt-140363-kingbright-optokoppler-phototransistor-kb-817-dip-4-transistor-ac-dc.pdf).

This is my current circuit:

[image: My circuit]

The problem is that my Raspberry Pi software is always reading the GPIO input pin as HIGH and it never switches to LOW.

I found that if I ground it via a multimeter to read the voltage it jumps to LOW. The jumper wires have a length of 20 cm between the optocoupler and the Raspberry Pi.

What could be the cause?

To add: The pin is set as input and also set with the internal pull up resistor. Whenever I read voltage between the GPIO and GND the PIN detects the rising edge. I also measured the voltages correctly, it is either 3,3V or 0.08V at the PIN - however the PIN still doesnt recognize a rising edge.

I coded to detect both edges and it always recognizes the falling edge, but never the rising edge. So whenever I enable or disable the 24V DC it starts the callback function. (the input pin is never 1 though)

Comment: Who knows. Did you remember to set the pin as input? If it is an output, the optocoupler can't force the pin low, but shorting the pin to ground with a multimeter lead will make it read 0.

Comment: A multimeter that is set to measure voltage won't "ground" the pin, unless it be faulty or severe noise be present (I doubt it) or it has set to measure current. I wonder if it grounds the pin, what do you read as voltage?

Comment: @user174174, a DMM in voltage mode won't ground the pin but it's input resistance (10 Mohm or suchlike) can pull a floating pin to a voltage that can read as a LOW if the pin's input leakage current is low enough. If the OP hasn't actually built the circuit they thought they had then it's a possibility. And empirically it appears to be what the OP's seeing.

Comment: The datasheet you linked does not match your schematic symbol... You cannot design electronics by picking "almost the correct part", it has to be the correct one...

Comment: Also there's pretty much never a reason to use an optocoupler for 24VDC signals. The only valid reason is when you suspect that the target ground is all over the place. Otherwise, voltage divider, protection diodes, high resistance series resistor towards GPIO pin, done. There's some sort of optocoupler religion formed by users of these hobbyist boards. Optocouplers are unreliable and expensive and at least in case of digital signals, outdated technology.

Comment: Maybe 27k is a bit high (=>4k7). What's the 1k resistor good for? Having both internal and external pullup is not making anything better. The CTR of this coupler is relatively low, so giving it a bit more current on the input might help. I assume that you handle the GPIO correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the bad image - it is a 2.7kOhm resistor.